# Hibernate interceptor for database auditing-delete operation is rolled back

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I need to create a single database table to store different changelog/auditing (when something was added, deleted, updated). I want to capture

```
id (for the event),
user that triggered it,
entity name,
entity id,
timestamp of the event
```

Through Hibernate inceptor I can able to audit both insertion and updation operation in the audit table but failed to audit the deleted entries.It doesn't throw any error but it gets rolled back somewhere.Can you provide the solution?

The interface is

```
public interface IAuditLog {
    
    public Long getId();    
}
```

The audit entity class is

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "auditlog")
public class AuditLog implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long auditLogId;
    private String action;
    private String detail;
    private Date createdDate;
    private long entityId;
    private String entityName;
        ...
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable, IAuditLog {
...
        
    @Override
    public Long getId(){
        return this.stockId.longValue();
    }
    
   
}
```

Interceptor class

```java
public class AuditLogInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor{
    
    private Set inserts = new HashSet();
    private Set updates = new HashSet();
    private Set deletes = new HashSet();
    
   @Autowired private static AuditRepo auditRepo;
        
    public boolean onSave(Object entity,Serializable id,
        Object[] state,String[] propertyNames,Type[] types)
        throws CallbackException {
        
        System.out.println("onSave");
        
        if (entity instanceof IAuditLog){
            inserts.add(entity);
        }
        return false;
            
    }
    
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity,Serializable id,
        Object[] currentState,Object[] previousState,
        String[] propertyNames,Type[] types)
        throws CallbackException {
    
        System.out.println("onFlushDirty");
        
        if (entity instanceof IAuditLog){
            updates.add(entity);
        }
        return false;
        
    }
    
    public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, 
        Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, 
        Type[] types) {
        
        System.out.println("onDelete");
        
        if (entity instanceof IAuditLog){
            deletes.add(entity);
        }
    }

  
    
    //called after committed into database
    public void postFlush(Iterator iterator) {
        
    try{
        
        for (Iterator it = inserts.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            IAuditLog entity = (IAuditLog) it.next();
            System.out.println("postFlush - insert");       
            logIt("Saved",entity);
        }   
            
        for (Iterator it = updates.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            IAuditLog entity = (IAuditLog) it.next();
            System.out.println("postFlush - update");
            logIt("Updated",entity);
        }   
            
        for (Iterator it = deletes.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            IAuditLog entity = (IAuditLog) it.next();`enter code here`
            System.out.println("postFlush - delete");
            logIt("Deleted",entity);
        }   
            
    } finally {
        inserts.clear();
        updates.clear();
        deletes.clear();
    }
  }     
    private void logIt(String action, Object entity) {
      try {
       ...
       //setting into auditlog
          auditRepo.save(auditLog);
      } catch (HibernateException e) {
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ditch your own custom solution and use something like Hibernate Envers or simply use a database trigger.

Comment: Your interceptor is flawed as well, auto wiring doesn't work for static fields, and the interceptor is a singleton so you are actually leaking state with the 3 collections.

Comment: Dont recreate the wheel, you should use Envers (https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa#hibernate) as suggested by @M.Deinum

Comment: I don't want to create audit tables for each entity as in hibernate envers but needs to audit in a single table itself.

Comment: You don't have to create an audit table for each entity in Envers. You can choose what you want to audit and where you want to audit it.

Comment: How to avoid the generation of audit tables for each entity?Suppose I want to audit Employee table.But I don't want the generation of employee_aud but I need revision_info table.

Comment: Note that DML statements aren't covered by interceptors, so it would be best if you use a tool like Debezium to do this change data capturing instead which works on the database level.